# What causes the urge to urinate at a physiological level?

Tags: urination

Can someone describe what causes a human the urge to urinate? I understand that it's highly correlated with bladder volume, but it is not causal as bladder spasm can occur even when very little urine is in the bladder. Furthermore, there are apparently foods that can irritate the bladder such that a spasm can occur at low volumes. Thus it appears there may be a mechanical (volume) as well as chemical trigger (irritants). How do both of these triggers occur in the body and how are they related? What causes the detrusor muscle to contract? How does the bladder know when it is full? etc...

Comment: You can read some online articles about urgent urination and urinary bladder physiology.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: @ChrisRogers I think this is already a reasonably researched question.

Comment: @BryanKrause - There may well be adequate research, or there may not.  There is no indication on what has been read and where. Is there an angle which has not been looked at? I can see a possibility within the question, but unless I know what has been read I cannot be certain.

Comment: @ChrisRogers I think you are mixing the requirements for answers and questions, or I may be mistaken on what our new standards are here. As-is, this question is just fine for Biology.SE for example, so if it needs to be migrated there so be it. OP is aware that there are multiple contributors to urge to urinate, that these involve mechanical and other mechanisms, etc. We can't quite require people to answer their own question to ask it or we'll be down to questions that require original research to answer and not ever be able to do so in the scope of SE.

Comment: @BryanKrause, "causes of urinary urgency" and "urinary bladder emptying physiology" are like two chapters from a medical book. An OP can get a simple and complete answer by reading some online articles.